# How to position content when background is set to 100vh

Tags: html, css

I've created a webpage with three sections. Each section is denoted by a background image, which takes up 100vh, so as to always fit the full size of your screen. You navigate between these panes by scrolling or using the navigation bar.

I cannot figure out how to position content within these sections that is more than thirty characters. It either 'jumps down' into the next section or runs across the page with no regard for width settings.

In short, I'm attempting to create a div that I can put different types of content within (blocks of text, embedded video/images, that will always be centered within its parent  tag.

I think the issue is being created by the way I'm defining my sections.

```
.zone {
color: white;
height: 100vh;
line-height: 100vh;
text-align: center;
}
.one {
  background: url("../img/code.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }
```

I've included a pen so you can see my code in full. Thank you for your feedback.

https://codepen.io/EnzoCodes/pen/GQvWrv

Comment: Try giving height in % rather than vh.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you meant by more than thirty characters but I added an answer that shows you how to centrally position elements inside your sections. If it wasnt quite what you were trying to do then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code is a bit messy couldnt really tell what you were going for. In order to position your about box in a new location inside your first section I made the section a flexbox. Here is the CSS I added:

```
  section:nth-child(1) {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .aboutBox {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
  }
```

The about box code is just to clean it up a little but the flexbox allows you to align the items inside the section. I centered the box perfectly inside the section. Here is an updated codepen: **https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXMBxa**

You arent limited to just this positioning. Here is a handy guide on flexbox that explains how it works and what you can do with it: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

---

An alternate way to position your content is by using absolute position on your section contents. You can then align the item using the top, left, right and bottom CSS rules. Here is a codepen showing your aboutbox as an absolutely positioned item inside the flexbox: **https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYLXQY**